# My server does not respond

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, node.js

I would like to have an address for my website like this : meteo.xyz.com

I own the domain xyz.com

I redirected the traffic from my domain to the digital ocean dns in my domain name provider :

meteo   CNAME   1800    ns1.digitalocean.com.
meteo   CNAME   1800    ns2.digitalocean.com.
meteo   CNAME   1800    ns3.digitalocean.com.

I added a A record in digital ocean pointing to my server ip :

A   meteo.xyz.com   directs to [ip]   3600

My nodejs app is running at 127.0.0.1:8080 on my server.

I can see it when i do ss -nplut :
tcp     LISTEN     0     511    127.0.0.1:8080

I created an apache virtualhost containing this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
         ServerName meteo
         ServerAlias meteo.xyz.com
         DocumentRoot /home/myname/meteo/dist/
 <Directory />
         Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
         Require all granted
 </Directory>
         ProxyRequests Off
         ProxyPreserveHost On
         ProxyVia Full
 <Proxy *>
         Require all granted
 </Proxy>
         ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
         ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
         # alert, emerg.
         LogLevel warn
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I load http at meteo.xyz.com it keeps saying "meteo.xyz.com took too long to respond"

Comment: can you ping meteo.xyz.com ? and get a success message ?

Comment: I do, it pings ns2.digitalocean.com

Comment: your cname is the problem. meteo CNAME 1800 ns1.digitalocean.com . metro should not point to ns1.digitalocean.com. it should point to root doman xyz.com

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: since you have a public ip as A record for the meteo.xyz.com, just delete CNAME you added meteo CNAME 1800 ns1.digitalocean.com.
meteo CNAME 1800 ns2.digitalocean.com.
meteo CNAME 1800 ns3.digitalocean.com. all threee

Comment: I deleted the three CNAME in my domain name provider and it is the same

Comment: You'd have to wait for the `TTL` (1800 seconds) for the caches to expire. (I'd recommend not using `CNAME`s at all until you have deeper understanding on DNS.)